# Jersey 2.25.1 post method

Tags: java, jersey

I am using the latest distribution of `jersey` framework and I am encountering some issue with the post method. I have to pass the instance of `ByteArrayInputStream` but it is not accepting it. I've gone through documentation but it doesn't explain it very well. And, how can I specify the MediaType?

```
Response tokenResponse = resourceGetToken.request()
                        .header( KeyConstants.REST_URI_APPENDERS, tokenSb )
                        .header( DocusignRESTContants.CONTENT_TYPE, DocusignRESTContants.APPLICATION_XML )
                        .header( DocusignRESTContants.X_DOCUSIGN_AUTHENTICATION, getDocusignAuthHeader( cu ) )
                        /*.accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML )*/
                        .post( Response.class, new ByteArrayInputStream( tokenStream.toString().getBytes() ) );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an [`Entity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html), where you can also specify the media-type for the body

There are static convenience methods like `xml` `json` `form` for `application/xml`, `application/json` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, respectively. But if you need a different type, then you can use the static `entity` method, where the second argument is the media type

```
.post(Entity.json(yourBody));
.post(Entity.xml(yourBody));
.post(Entity.entity(yourBody, yourMediaType));
```

Also there is already the `MediaType` class. Unless your constants are using non-standard media types, you're better of just using the `MediaType` constants, like `MediaType.APPLICAITON_XML`

Comment: So, can I say like this 
    `.post(Entity.xml( new ByteArrayInputStream( tokenStream.toString().getBytes() ) ) );`

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to

Comment: Cool it is going through. Thanks peeskillet.